# TSQL - Alternative resultset when IN clause returns empty

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need help to implement a filter within a bigger CTE query.

Imagine this scenario:

- List of items that may belong to several categories.
- User follows one of those categories.
- Filter: user MAY specify that when one category is followed he/she only wants to view items that also belong to at least one of the auxiliary categories he/she can specify.

Example: user follows the category 'Computers' and specified that only wants to view 'Tablets'. When the user views 'Computers', the query should only select items that also belong to the 'Tablets' category. When there are no filters specified, all items of the main category ('Computers') should be presented.

SQL Fiddle seems to have some problem at the moment, [so here's a little schema and query (at the end)](https://db.tt/Fen17NZ5) that illustrate the problem

```
SELECT * FROM ItemsToShowWithCategories itswh_cte1
WHERE /* Other filters AND */
    itswh_cte1.ItemPk IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT itswh_cte2.ItemPk
        FROM ItemsToShowWithCategories AS itswh_cte2
        INNER JOIN ItemsToShowWithCategories AS itswh3_cte
            ON itswh_cte2.ItemPk=itswh3_cte.ItemPk
        LEFT JOIN CategoriesRequiredByCategory_CTE AS crbc_cte
            ON itswh_cte2.FkCategory=crbc_cte.FkCategoryView
           AND crbc_cte.FkCategoryRequired=itswh3_cte.FkCategory
        WHERE crbc_cte.FkCategoryView IS NOT NULL
    );
```

Question: **how can I return all the records when the IN clause returns empty?**

Comment: very well formated question with examples +1

Comment: Why LEFT JOIN crbc_cte when WHERE crbc_cte.FkCategoryView IS NOT NULL? That's a regular INNER JOIN. Also no need for DISTINCT in the sub-select, makes no difference.

Comment: You're right, that was the result of a few different attempts... and ended up like that before posting. That is the bit where I need help to return the data I need for the different cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the most obvious would be something like this:

```
WHERE /* Other filters AND */
    itswh_cte1.ItemPk IN (
        SELECT itswh_cte2.ItemPk
        FROM ItemsToShowWithCategories AS itswh_cte2
        INNER JOIN ItemsToShowWithCategories AS itswh3_cte
            ON itswh_cte2.ItemPk=itswh3_cte.ItemPk
        LEFT JOIN CategoriesRequiredByCategory_CTE AS crbc_cte
            ON itswh_cte2.FkCategory=crbc_cte.FkCategoryView
           AND crbc_cte.FkCategoryRequired=itswh3_cte.FkCategory
        WHERE crbc_cte.FkCategoryView IS NOT NULL
    )
    or 
    (SELECT count(ItemPk)
        FROM ItemsToShowWithCategories AS itswh_cte2
        INNER JOIN ItemsToShowWithCategories AS itswh3_cte
            ON itswh_cte2.ItemPk=itswh3_cte.ItemPk
        LEFT JOIN CategoriesRequiredByCategory_CTE AS crbc_cte
            ON itswh_cte2.FkCategory=crbc_cte.FkCategoryView
           AND crbc_cte.FkCategoryRequired=itswh3_cte.FkCategory
        WHERE crbc_cte.FkCategoryView IS NOT NULL) = 0
```

There's a few variants you could try if this performs poorly, for example using `(select top 1 ItemPk ...) is null` or something like that. A CTE will allow you to avoid writing the same SQL twice (useful if this isn't generated SQL).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, this solution fails in the last case, when you have specified an auxiliary category to be filtered and there are no items with that category. It is selecting all items and should be selecting none.

Comment: @ca2s7l Well, in that case, why don't you just make a check for whether the category is selected or not?

Comment: It seems to be working if the in the last join we change equal to different in the category required. Like this: ... AND crbc_cte.FkCategoryRequired<>itswh3_cte.FkCategory. This seems to make it work. Thanks for your help!